# node.js send commands to non js child process shell

Tags: node.js, fork, spawn

I'm using inkscape's CLI from node.js, this works already fine, I'v heard that this would be more performant if I was using the --shell parameter of inkscape so the idea is to leave a process open and just send commands whenever I want to execute them to the child.

I tried using spawn (this command does open an svg file):

```
 const child = spawn(`${inkscapePath} "${projectPathSvg}"`, { shell: true })
```

If I don't put shell:true it doesn't look like is doing anything, and with shell:true is going to open an inkscape tab but without window, but anyways this is not doing a whole lot, when I try to use child.send(command) I get an error:
[image]

Any ideas or tutorials on how to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inkscape --shell` is a completely different thing than what `shell` means in `spawn`. The latter just means that you are running the process in a new shell, like `bash`. `--shell` for inkscape means that you will be put in a REPL shell where you can send commands to a running inkscape process.

Furthermore, the `child.send` you are referring to only works when an IPC channel was established with the child, which doesn't happen in `spawn`, only in `fork` which only works when the child is a nodejs process again.

What you really seem to be wanting to do then is to communicate with the open shell process of `inkscape --shell`, sending commands programmatically from nodejs. For this you'll need to use the stdin and stdout pipes setup by spawn.

Something like this might work:

```
const inkscape = spawn('inkscape', ['--shell']);
inkscape.stdin.write('my-inkscape-command');
```

Not sure whether inkscape has an API that would be better suited than this, but the approach seems worth exploring.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, this is working from the terminal, I have to open two terminals one to launch inkscape window and the other to open shelll like "inkscape -q --shell", and then I can run any commands. I tried on nodejs with your solution, but I'm getting on the console: stdout: command, but is not doing anything, in theory this should be working, so maybe I'm not reaching stdin?

code

     exec(`${inkscapePath} ${projectPathSvg}`)
      const ls = spawn(`${inkscapePath}`, ['-q', '--shell'])

      setInterval(() => {
        ls.stdin.write('select-clear');
      }, 10000);

Comment: I have it working! I was missing a line break that is needed to trigger the command on the shell